# Automatic function linked to an external timer

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement, timer, conditional-statements

I have an automatic function, the idea is to execute in an specific time some actions.

It receives a ListView with the actions and specific times.

[image: Actions for automatic]

It runs almost pefect. I say almost because sometimes it doesn't executes one action (lets say action #10, and it has 30 actions to do) and when this happen the rest of the actions neither get executed.

I have some validations where I check if the previous actions is executed then the current one is excuted, but it doesn't make any difference, it continues stopping at some point.

Here the code for this automatic function:

Constructor

```
public RunAutomatic()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            stopwatch = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            stopwatch.Interval = 5;
            stopwatch.Tick += new EventHandler(stopwatch_Tick);
            repSeconds = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < repeatActions.Capacity; x++)
            {
                repeatActions.Add(x);
                finished.Add(x);
            }
        }
```

Run Function

```
private void RunFaster()
{
    if (contPos > 1)
    {
        ArrayList tmp = (ArrayList)repeatActions[contPos - 1];
        if ((bool)tmp[tmp.Count - 1] == true) //This is where it is supposed to validate that the previous action is already executed
            Execute(2);
        else
        {
            contPos = contPos - 1;
            Execute(2);
        }
    }
    else
        Execute(2);
}
```

I have tried to solve this but can't get over it.
Thanks to all replies.

Comment: What exception are you getting?  Is the first time it runs, `tmp.Count == 0`, so you're indexing an array with `-1`?

Comment: Thanks @JohnCarpenter. I don't get any exception. Simply doesn't execute the action.  "tmp.count" is used to get all the items in the arraylist, which the last item is a bool, where it says the action is alredy executed or not. The "tmp" arraylist is filled with the "repeatActions" item at the specific position. The items in "repeatAcions" already have some parameters.

Comment: It's unclear, also, exactly what you're trying to do.  Is it a dumb question to ask what is an automatic function? Are you trying to execute a sequence of actions in the background?

Comment: Thanks @JohnCarpenter. This a function that it's included in an energy simulator. So, this function gets the instructions and starts executing the actions in the specified time. Not in background, because this function takes the full control of the simulator to start operating and executing actions. Let me upload a video and give you the url so it will be clearer.

Comment: @JohnCarpenter Here the video about how this works: https://youtu.be/JJ0Er0HgWZA

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzew_qYCrKV3MXpyRGRQamE2WUk   -  @JohnCarpenter  And here a screenshot where you can see that in the list the action at 00:30:15 was not executed so the rest neither, and the time on the simulator is 1:52:24, this is my problem, If one action is skipped at it's time on simulator the rest of the actions are also skipped and my function do nothing else.

Comment: I don't really need to know what the whole program does.  I just need to understand what it is your sample code is supposed to do.  What is `stopwatch_Tick()`?  What does `Execute()` do?  What is `repeatActions`?  Also, it's not clear what your general desired behavior is.  It seems trivial to do something like `foreach (action in actions) { action(); }`, but based on your description I'm not sure why this wouldn't work.

Comment: I have a stopwatch which is linked to the general timer of the simulator, so I don't have control on it, this stopwatch is used because the speed of the general timer can be changed, so, in each step (lets say its working 3x), the stopwatch_tick is used to verify the actions from the second 0 to second 2 and execute them, on next step it will verify from second 3 to second 5. And works sometimes until the end, others just skip actions and don't execute the rest of them. The video isn't about all simulator, is only to show how this automatic function works in the environment. @JohnCarpenter